# Incorporate LinkedIn to a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, api, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm trying to create a webpage that can incorporate LinkedIn info's (profile,people,company, etc...).
The things that it can/would do are the following:

When the user enters a name that is registered in LinkedIn, he gets the following

*Name, Company, Email
*List of LinkedIn messages that are waiting for reply

The same process goes on everytime the user adds a profile, I'm planning to use the Profile API of LinkedIn to get the Name, Company and Email but I can't find a working example to be my basis.

As for the 2nd one I still don't know how to get the LinkedIn messages.

Here's my Layout and expected result.
How can I achieved this? Opinions and Suggestions are highly appreciated tnx

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is far to broad a question for me to invest the necessary time in to figure the answers (multiple) for you, but do let me give you some hints. First of all, from my experience with the linkedin API not all the data you wish to access is available (do double check this though, I used the API quite awhile back and stuff might have changed in the meantime). As this data is not available through the API the only alternative would be to somehow bypass the cross domain policy, which in conclusion would require the user to install a chrome extension/firefox plugin which will function as a proxy for your application or even 'better', make you entire application a browser plugin based web app. Not that I am a fan of those whatsoever but if you application is meant in any way whatsoever as a linkedin (dedicated) plugin (probably as part of a greater service you're developing) then it might make most sense.

Answer (score 2):

The whole system you are describing is very long winded and requires a large amount of development time. Alot of the data is not accessible directly or indirectly too. You cannot get email address's out from the API as a security feature (bots could just harvest emails for marketing campaigns).

First of all, you will need to make an application that allows for oAuth2 connections with the linkedin API service. People will log onto your website, click to join their linkedin account with your website and your website will receive back an access token to do the calls.

You will then need to build the queries which will access the data you require. The linkedin API documentation (http://developer.linkedin.com/) isn't greatly indepth but it gives you a good understand and points you where you need to go. There are also a couple of pre-done php API's around such as https://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/.

I have worked with many API's from twitters, facebooks and LinkedIn's and they all require a lot of back-end work to make sure that they are secure and get the correct data.

It would take me hours to go through exactly how to do it and has taken me many hours to get a solid implementation in place and working with all the different calls available.

If you have minimal coding knowledge, it would be best to go to an external company with a large amount of resources and knowledge in the field who can do it for you. Otherwise it may take many months to get a working prototype.